# Set Node.js environment variables in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, environment-variables, webstorm

Is there any way to set environment variables when running a Node.js app using JetBrains' official Node plugin for WebStorm (and their other IDEs as well)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible from WebStorm, environment variables should be [defined in your system](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160).

UPDATE: in the new versions it's possible to set environment variables in the Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: So in my case, they are defined in my system, but when my node app is running the process.env object is empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: Zainan is correct.  You can set environment variables in the run/debug configuration.  I just confirmed this works for me (IDEA 12.1.3) by setting the NODE_ENV variable.

Comment: @DanTanner, this feature was added later. At the time of my response it was not possible.

Answer (score 51):

It is actually possible
Here is the official doc:
http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html

Here is my screenshot[image]

Comment: Is it possible dynamically? I would like to define CHROME_BIN=`which google-chrome || which chromium-browser`?

Comment: Hi how do i open this window? can someone provide the steps?

Comment: @anandhu you go to Run->Edit Configurations->Pick the configuration you want from the left or create a new Node.js run configuration->Environment Variables-> Little icon that looks like a sheet of paper on the right of the Environment Variables field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to JetBrains products, i'm not sure if this is the official solution.

Sharing the steps I took resolve this issue.

> Note: I'm using NPM package manager.

In WebStorm menu, go to `Run -> Edit Configuration -> click  +  -> npm`

then provide the following fields:

- Package.json
- Command: run
- Scripts: start
- Environment: MY_ENV_NAME=123456

Click Ok

[image]

Then select the run configuration:

[image]

Finally got the nodejs server up and running:
[image]

Comment: Helped me. This works also for `npm install`. Of course, you then have to click the play button, because if you write directly in the terminal `npm install` it won't work.