# NODE_ENV is showing undefined although i set environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using webstorm and i tried to set the environment variable using

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

and when i check the for environment variable using

```
echo%NODE_ENV%
```

i get development as the answer.

But in my node application when i check for the variable using

```
 var b= process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

i get

`b:undefined`

I even tried using the following in the package.json file

```
"start": "set  node ./bin/www && NODE_ENV=production "
```

still i am getting undefined. I dont know whats the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use export instead

`"start": "export NODE_ENV=production && node ./bin/www"`

Comment: What node version do you have ?
`$node -v`

Comment: 8.9.4  . when i checked the process.env in the debugger it does not include the NODE_ENV environment variable. seems like it has not latched to the process object

Comment: i tried this program in VS code and wrote the following in powershell. $env:NODE_ENV="development" ; node www . this seems to work. but it is not working in webstorm

Comment: If you are using webstrom terminal, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707329/set-node-js-environment-variables-in-webstorm its not possible to directly set node_env using command however you can set `environment variable` in node.js `Run/Debug Configuration` http://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html#d149998e16

Answer (score 3):

You should first set the variable and then run the script:

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node ./bin/www"
```

Note that this will only work on Windows. If you want a cross-platform solution, use the [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www
```

Comment: i tried that at first it didnt work so i switched them but still noot working

Comment: @PuskarShestha You can try the `cross-env` package.

Comment: i am currently on windows but I tried that but it is still not working.

Comment: @PuskarShestha What do you get when you `console.log(process.env)`?

Comment: i checked the process.env using a debugger and there is no NODE_ENV inside there. seems like the variable hasnt latched itself to the process object

Comment: @PuskarShestha What happens if you use a different variable (for example TEST instead of NODE_ENV)? Maybe something in your application is deleting the NODE_ENV variable.

Comment: i tried this program in VS code and wrote the following in powershell. $env:NODE_ENV="development" ; node www  . this seems to work. but it is not working in webstorm

Answer (score 0):

The following is what works for me, as my goal is trying to keep package dependency to what I really need:

```
"startwin": "SET NODE_ENV=production& SET SOME_TOKEN=123abc& node ./bin/www",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production SOME_TOKEN=123abc node ./bin/www"
```

A drawback is each time another environment var is needed, I have 2 places to edit, but that's hardly any effort (at least in my case, yours might be different).

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am still getting undefined

Comment: i tried this program in VS code and wrote the following in powershell. $env:NODE_ENV="development" ; node www . this seems to work. but it is not working in webstorm

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate config.js being required, make sure it is first. You may have a race condition.

I ran into something like this yesterday. It may or may not be your issue. When I ran my code, my environment variable was undefined. I moved an entire library into a separate module. I required that module. My problem was that my requires were out of order, so when it asked, it wasn't set yet. I moved my config.js require up above my library package require.